# How to delete duplicate rows without unique ID

Tags: postgresql, duplicates

| Id | SleepDay | TotalMinutesAsleep | TotalTimeInBed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8378563200 | 4/20/2016 | 381 | 409 |
| 8378563200 | 4/21/2016 | 396 | 417 |
| 8378563200 | 4/22/2016 | 441 | 469 |
| 8378563200 | 4/23/2016 | 565 | 591 |
| 8378563200 | 4/24/2016 | 458 | 492 |
| 8378563200 | 4/25/2016 | 388 | 402 ---> this is the duplicate |
| 8378563200 | 4/25/2016 | 388 | 402 |
| 8378563200 | 4/26/2016 | 550 | 584 |
| 8378563200 | 4/27/2016 | 531 | 600 |

This is part of my table and how can I delete the duplicate row? I use CTE clause but it deleted all records of id #8378563200 on 4/25/2016.

Answer (score 4):

Without column(s) to identify a unique row?
Then you could use `ctid`.

> **ctid**
>
> The physical location of the row version within its table. Note
> that although the ctid can be used to locate the row version very
> quickly, a row's ctid will change if it is updated or moved by VACUUM
> FULL. Therefore ctid is useless as a long-term row identifier. A
> primary key should be used to identify logical rows

For example:

> ```
> delete 
>  from SleepLogs log1
> using SleepLogs log2
> where log2.Id = log1.Id
>   and log2.SleepDay = log1.SleepDay
>   and log2.TotalMinutesAsleep = log1.TotalMinutesAsleep
>   and log2.TotalTimeInBed = log1.TotalTimeInBed
>   and log2.ctid < log1.ctid;
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from SleepLogs
> ```

> | id | sleepday | totalminutesasleep | totaltimeinbed |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 8378563200 | 2016-04-20 | 381 | 409 |
> | 8378563200 | 2016-04-21 | 396 | 417 |
> | 8378563200 | 2016-04-22 | 441 | 469 |
> | 8378563200 | 2016-04-23 | 565 | 591 |
> | 8378563200 | 2016-04-24 | 458 | 492 |
> | 8378563200 | 2016-04-25 | 388 | 402 |
> | 8378563200 | 2016-04-26 | 550 | 584 |
> | 8378563200 | 2016-04-27 | 531 | 600 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2e6b0c503edcebb7d10d5433c02c30d7)*

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
DELETE
FROM table1
WHERE ctid IN (SELECT ctid
               FROM (SELECT ctid,
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                                PARTITION BY Id, SleepDay,TotalMinutesAsleep,TotalTimeInBed ) AS rn
                     FROM table1) t
               WHERE rn > 1);
```

Replace `table1` with your own table name.

Comment: `DELETE FROM SleepDay_merged
        WHERE ctid IN (
 SELECT ctid FROM (
  SELECT ctid,sleepday,totalsleeprecords
  FROM SleepDay_merged
  GROUP BY ctid,sleepday,totalsleeprecords
  HAVING COUNT(*)>1) AS to_delete
                 );` I tried to use GROUP BY but it doesn't work. Why?